# Subset rows from a dataframe which is not part of another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let say I have two `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'col2' : ['Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']})
dat1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['A', 'C',], 'col2' : ['Z', 'Y']})
```

Now I need to return those rows of `dat1` for which the column combination `col1` and `col2` are not available in `dat2`

For example, I need to return rows 2 and 3 from `dat1` as new dataframe.

Is there any direct method to get the same?

Comment: `dat1.merge(dat2, on=['col1','col2'], how='outer', indicator=True)`, then you can query the indicator column. This assumes that `dat2` are row unique, if not, drop duplicates before merge.